# How can I normalize gamestates in order to use with a machine learning library?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, deep-learning

I have currently collected 150000 gamestates from playing a Monte Carlo Tree Search AI player against a basic rule based AI at the game of [Castle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castle_(card_game)). The information captured represents the information available to the MCTS player on the start of each of their turn and whether they won the game in the end. They are stored within CVS files.

Example gamestate entry:
[image: Example game state entry:]

For example the entry above shows that:

- **HAND:** MCTS player's hand contains the cards 7,5,4,9,9,9 (suit has been omitted because it has no baring on the game). *(list of cards)*
- **CASTLE_FU:** MCTS face up cards are 8,2,10 *(list of cards)*
- **CASTLE_FD_SIZE:** MCTS has 3 cards face down *(int)*
- **OP_HAND_SIZE:** The opponent has 3 cards in their hand *(int)*
- **OP_CASTLE_FU:** The opponents face up cards are Jack, Queen, Ace. *(list of cards)*
- **OP_CASTLE_FD_SIZE:** The opponent has 3 cards face down *(int)*
- **TOP:** The top of the discard pile is a 4 *(single value)*
- **DECK_EMPTY:** The deck in which players pick up cards is not empty *(boolean)*
- **WON:** The MCTS player ended up winning the hand *(boolean)*

I hope to input this data into machine learning algorithms to produce an evaluation function for the MCTS algorithm to use.

**How can I normalize this data so I can use it in Keras/Scikit-Learn?**

### EDIT:

I'm not sure normalizing is the right term here. **Encoding** or **mapping** may be more accurate for what I am trying to achieve. Another difficulty I've encountered is the fact that the players hand size can vary up to almost holding the full deck in theory (although this would be incredibly rare in practice). However this is the only column that can be of a size greater than 3.

### EDIT 2:

I've come up with this model to represent the data. Does this look suitable?

[image]